# MVC3 - nullable type (Form didn`t send values to controller)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I trying resolve this problem during this two days. Unfortunately I am not able to do it. I don`t understand why my "form" send null values to some class. Have you hot idea what I have to do? Really this problem is nervous me.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'Id_tow' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Int32, System.String)'
>   in 'SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers.CartController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary
>   contains a null entry for parameter 'Id_tow' of non-nullable type
>   'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult
>   AddToCart(Int32, System.String)' in
>   'SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers.CartController'. An optional parameter
>   must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an
>   optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Here is this form:

```
@model SportsStore.WebUI.Models.SomeView
@using SportsStore.WebUI.HtmlHelpers
@using SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers
@using SportsStore.Entities

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>List</h2>

@foreach (var p in Model.Towar)
{
<div class="item">
<h3>@p.Nazwa</h3>
@p.Opis

@using(Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart")) {
@Html.HiddenFor(x => @p.Id_tow)
@Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
<input type="submit" value="+ Add to cart" />
}

<h4>@p.Cena.ToString("c")</h4>
</div>
}

<h2>List</h2>

@foreach (var b in Model.Kategorie)
{
<div class="item">
<h3>@b.Nazwa</h3>
</div>
}

<div class="pager">
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List",
new {page = x, category = Model.CurrentCategory}))
</div>
```

In my opinion is show correct values but send null to class (HTML source)

```
<div class="item">
<h3>Piłka</h3>
Piłka Firmy Nike

<form action="/Cart/AddToCart" method="post"><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id_tow must be a number." data-val-required="The Id_tow field is required." id="p_Id_tow" name="p.Id_tow" type="hidden" value="1" /><input id="returnUrl" name="returnUrl" type="hidden" value="/" /><input type="submit" value="+ Add to cart" />
</form>
<h4>59,80 zł</h4>
</div>
```

Part of Controller Cart which get nulls values:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(int Id_tow, string returnUrl)
            {
                Towar product = repository.Towar
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id_tow == Id_tow);
                if (product != null)
                {
                    GetCart().AddItem(product, 1);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
            }
```

If I will put my values everything working correct but of course this not fix a problem

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(int Id_tow = 1, string returnUrl = "www.gmail.com")
            {
                Towar product = repository.Towar
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id_tow == Id_tow);
                if (product != null)
                {
                    GetCart().AddItem(product, 1);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
            }
```

**This fix problem if not your help I will be not able to fix this. Thanks**

```
@foreach (var p in Model.Towar)
{
<div class="item">
<h3>@p.Nazwa</h3>
@p.Opis

@{
    int Id_tow = @p.Id_tow;
}


@using(Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart")) {
@Html.HiddenFor(x => Id_tow)
@Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
<input type="submit" value="+ Add to cart" />
}

<h4>@p.Cena.ToString("c")</h4>
</div>
}
```

Comment: The input name(p.Id_tow) and the parameter name(Id_tow) aren't the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(int Id_tow, string returnUrl)
            {
                Towar product = repository.Towar
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id_tow == Id_tow);
                if (product != null)
                {
                    GetCart().AddItem(product, 1);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
            }
```

with

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Towar tow, string returnUrl)
            {
                Towar product = repository.Towar
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id_tow == tow.Id_tow);
                if (product != null)
                {
                    GetCart().AddItem(product, 1);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
            }
```

Or you could use `Html.Hidden("Id_tow",  @p.Id_tow)` but this would not be recommended as it creates a bit of a brittle dependency between the View and the Controller.

Comment: it`s add something (buuton is working) but when I click link "what was bought" I see nothing

Comment: So does it return a valid value from repository.Towar
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id_tow == tow.Id_tow); or is that just returning null when you debug it?

Comment: Can you look to my post -> "Do you know how declared this correct? Maybe this is a problem?" because I think good declaration can fix this problem. Your idea is dubing correct but I can`t see values. "Towar" in my database is a table.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be seen in the following section of the generated hmtl:

```
id="p_Id_tow" name="p.Id_tow"
```

this difference in names prevents the mvc routing engine from associating the values of the hidden field with the parameter named Id_tow.  The simplest solution is to change the name of the paramter to match the id or name of the field.

Comment: public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(int p_Id_tow, string returnUrl = "www.wp.pl" ){} I change here name to take this value but problem is all the time.